# Switch information using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am thinking of applying a new page to the admin section on my website and I wanted to make one page with three tabs ( picture should be included ) is this possible using jQuery.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible.

In fact, there are [built in jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) [and](http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/) [enumerable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html) [plugins](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-tabs-plugin-idtabs/) [which](http://kuujinbo.info/ajax/jq_tabs.aspx) [do](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SmartTab) the job.

Comment: ha... thats the only one that was filtered by work proxy servers. So I couldnt even check it, but thought i'd include it as it came up in a search.

Answer (score 3):

There are several jQuery tabs plugins out there:

- [jquery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
- [jQuery Tools tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html)
- [Yetii](http://www.kminek.pl/lab/yetii/) (more lightweight solution)
- Create your own

If you don't need much functionality then just create your own with 3 links/elements and a set of `<div>` (or any other container) elements.

Answer (score 1):

It sure is. But you don't even need jQuery to do this. CSS can do this quite simply.
See [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/) for some examples.